# error in julia - pyplot - error 6034

Tags: julia

i am starting to use Julia and i have to do plot. When i call PyPlot in Julia, appears the error 6034.

```
R6034
An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I tried to reinstall, downgrade, upgrade julia, I use atom to write. How could i proceed ? o use `pkg.add` ,`pkg.build` , `pkg.update`, `pycall.`

Is there a phyton problem ? or a gfortran problem ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399480/julia-runtime-error-when-using-pyplot - you can see the solution there, though it was never properly marked as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

using the solution suggested in the other question does not solve my problem. When I try to set
`ENV("PYTHON")`
I get the following error:

> MethodError: objects of type Base.EnvHash are not callable

Comment: set ENV["PYTHON"] to the path/name of the python executable
 (note the square brackets - it's a Dict). It might be sufficient to remove PyCall, add it again and re-`build` it

Comment: Try reading https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl/blob/0550f890c86878375f74821a459da41e7cc943f6/README.md#installation

Comment: I tried all your hints and non of them worked ... I reinstalled PyCall, set the Path manually, rebuild Python and so on. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd probably try opening an issue on PyCall.jl - they should be able to help you.